# submit for review issue

Tags: wp-admin, review

I have installed WordPress on my linode vps and it was running without a problem till today.

Today I realized I dont have admin rights to post a page in wp-admin. It doesn't show me submit button, it shows me "submit for review" button instead. It is very odd because I am logged in with admin account and for example I can use theme editor, edit styles etc. I googled it and found something about "auto increment on primary keys are gone".

What do you think?

Comment: any idea ?i really need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird.. Have you checked the database on your own?

1. Are you in the administrator group? Get your user id from the `{tableprefix}_users` table and search for the coresponding meta key `{tableprefix}_user_level` for your user id inside the `{tableprefix}_usermeta` table. The value should be set to `10`.
2. Do you have migrated the database from another wordpress installation? If it's really an autoincrement problem, you could use a db tool (e.g. phpMyAdmin) to set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute. I haven't tested this, so please make a database backup before and use a testsystem. Open your database, select a table (e.g. `{tableprefix}_posts`), click the `Structure` tab and edit the `ID` column. There you can enable/disable the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute for this column. Another approach is to export the hole database with the `Add AUTO_INCREMENT value` selected, delete and re-import the database.

Answer (score 3):

Got stuck with this problem with one of our websites after we used the tumblr import tool. The tool did not import the blog successfully and also introduced this problem.

I fixed this by removing the auto-draft posts post with a very large id something above 2billion in my case and reseting the auto-increment to something like 2000 depending on how many rows you had before in the wp-posts table.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after forklifting data into the wp_posts table. I had explicitly set the primary key value (ID field in wp_posts) and now the autoincrement was set to start at somewhere north of a billion (loading a book's ISBN as the ID).

To fix, I culled the data and then did an alter table and set the autoincrement appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this issue on my wordpress site.

I compared staging db and live db then got an interested thing: the auto increment index is missing in configuration of wp_posts table. That why we can't publish post, page or portfolio.

Below are sql query to update value for auto increment of posts table.

ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` MODIFY `ID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=421;

421: can change to other number, ensure it's higher than last post id